# accept user input and add to a file in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a requirement like I need to add the contents to a file parallelly, not like read statement.
Somewhat like

cat >> filename <

This should be included in a bash script.

Comment: Your question is not so clear, you should reformulate it

Comment: Your suggestion served my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at tee(2)

```
$> cat test 
old data

$> tee >> test
hello

$> cat test 
old data
hello
```

I'm not sure I understood what you mean with

> add the contents to a file parallelly

Comment: I meant accept input from user and keep on appending to the new line of the file till the user ends